# PHP SET default argument in function as static variable

Tags: php, static, arguments, default, default-value

is it possible to set the default value of an argument in a class function as static variable
thanks for the help in Advance!

```
class UserControl {

    public static $CurrentUID;

    public static function isUserExist($CurrentUID = UserControl::$CurrentUID){

     ....

    }
}
```

Comment: It's not possible, as said in [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default), `The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a class member or a function call.`

Comment: ahh.. of course makes strings only

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make a workaround in this case:

```
public static function isUserExist($CurrentUID = false)
{
   if(!$CurrentUID)
      $CurrentUID = UserControl::$CurrentUID;
   ....
}
```

Comment: Unfortuntely my function is called in a tight loop, so the conditional is costly